# GCD algorithm Java

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I am very new to Java and I would like to ask for an explanation of a very simple code. It is supposed to find the GCD (greatest common divisor) of some two numbers. Sadly, I cannot understand the logic behind the checkGCD function. What exactly happens to *b* and *a mod b* that allows to get common denominator?

```
private static int checkGCD (int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    return checkGCD(b, a%b);
}
```

Comment: This is a Java implementation of the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

If the value passed to b is 0 it will return value of a other wise it will again chechGcd with the valuess b and a modulus b it called recursion

Answer (score 0):

Examples are always most helpful for me, here's a good example from Wikipedia, that actually explains how the algorithm functions:

For illustration, the Euclidean algorithm can be used to find the greatest common divisor of a = 1071 and b = 462. To begin, multiples of 462 are subtracted from 1071 until the remainder is less than 462. Two such multiples can be subtracted (q0 = 2), leaving a remainder of 147:

```
1071 = 2 × 462 + 147.
```

Then multiples of 147 are subtracted from 462 until the remainder is less than 147. Three multiples can be subtracted (q1 = 3), leaving a remainder of 21:

```
462 = 3 × 147 + 21.
```

Then multiples of 21 are subtracted from 147 until the remainder is less than 21. Seven multiples can be subtracted (q2 = 7), leaving no remainder:

```
147 = 7 × 21 + 0.
```

Since the last remainder is zero, the algorithm ends with 21 as the greatest common divisor of 1071 and 462. This agrees with the gcd(1071, 462) found by prime factorization above.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Worked_example

Answer (score 0):

A number divides a and b if and only if it divides b and a – b.

By repeatedly subtracting b, that means that a number divides a and b if and only if it divides b and a % b.  (a % b stands for the remainder after dividing a by b.)

Since the numbers that divide a and b are the same as the numbers that divide b and a % b, then, in particular, the greatest common divisor of a and b is the same as the  greatest common divisor of b and a % b.

Thus, to find the GCD of two numbers, you can replace the larger by the remainder after dividing the larger by the smaller.  And you can do that repeatedly until the smaller divides the larger without remainder.  That smaller one is the GCD of the original two numbers.

This [link with examples](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm) can be helpful.